# Does anyone know why I am getting this IllegalMonitorStateException?

Tags: java, concurrency

I have an integration test that launches getty and it in turn launches a web application. 
The web app will span some asynchronous threads that will run initialization tasks. After that it is ready to be tested. Now because I've to wait one of those tasks to finish I thought of putting a static monitor in a shared class:

```
private static Object bootstrapDone = new Object();
```

with the following accessor methods:

```
public static void signalEsBoostrapCompleted(){
    synchronized (bootstrapDone){
        bootstrapDone.notifyAll();
    } 
}

public static void waitEsBoostrapCompleted() throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized (bootstrapDone){
        bootstrapDone.wait(20000);
    } 
}
```

If I run this in a test I get:
Exception in thread "Thread-11" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notifyAll(Native Method)

from the line where the notifyAll is. I have no idea why this is happening. 
Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you ever changing the value of `bootstrapDone` anywhere? (I'd suggest making the variable final...)

Comment: Is bootstrap done being reassigned by anything? Even if it isn't, you should make it `final` as well. Objects you create specifically to lock on should usually be constants (i.e `final`)

Comment: Indeed they should be, but I was trying to quickly write a test and in the rush I forgot that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only obvious way I can think of that is possible is:  Something is changing the value of `bootstrapDone` on another thread, between the call to `synchronized(bootstrapDone)` and the call `bootstrapDone.notifyAll()`.

Make `bootstrapDone` final and whatever can no longer be compiled is likely to be the culprit.

Comment: Indeed, there was piece of code changing the object referenced by it. Making it final helped me find it in a snap. Thanks.